# Count no of lines and words from string

Tags: java, string, split, java.util.scanner

I want to count the number of words and lines from a string content.
here is my code:

```
private int[] getLineAndWordCount(final String textContent) {
    int wordCount = 0;
    int lineCount = 0;
    if (textContent.length() > 0) {
        textContent = textContent.replace("\t", " ");
        String[] newLineArrays = textContent.split("\n");
        lineCount = newLineArrays.length;
        for (String newLineStr : newLineArrays) {
            String[] wordsArray = newLineStr.trim().split(" ");
            for (String word : wordsArray) {
                if (word.length() > 0) {
                    wordCount++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return new int[]{lineCount, wordCount};
}
```

This codes works fine but during exceution it will create so many subStrings. So is there any other effective way to do the same thing. Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you just iterate through every character of the string / file? You could just count the spaces, tabs and newlines.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `java.util.Scanner`. For instance:

```
Scanner textScanner = new Scanner(text);
while (textScanner.hasNextLine()) {
    linesCount++;
    Scanner wordsScanner = new Scanner(textScanner.nextLine());
    while (wordsScanner.hasNext()) {
        wordsCount++;
        wordsScanner.next();
    }
}
```

A javadoc for `java.util.Scanner`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: Scanner internally create substring so the problem is same

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way.

```
    Scanner scanner=new Scanner(new File("Location"));
    int numberOfLines=0;
    StringTokenizer stringTokenizer=null;
    int numberOfWords=0;
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
         stringTokenizer=new StringTokenizer(scanner.nextLine()," ");
         numberOfWords=numberOfWords+stringTokenizer.countTokens();
         numberOfLines++;
    }
    System.out.println("Number of lines :"+numberOfLines);
    System.out.println("Number of words :"+numberOfWords);
```

Comment: Scanner internally create substring so the problem is same

Answer (score 0):

Usig Regex

```
 String str = "A B C\n D E F\n";
         Pattern compile = Pattern.compile("\n");
         Matcher matcher = compile.matcher(str);
         int count = 0;
         while(matcher.find()){
             count++;
         }
         System.out.println(count);//2
          count=0;
   Pattern compile1 = Pattern.compile("\\s+");
         Matcher matcher1 = compile1.matcher(str);

         while(matcher1.find()){
             count++;
         }
         System.out.println(count);//6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this

```
int line=str.trim().split("\n").length;
int words=str.trim().split("\\s+").length;
```